# EventWaiter - Java Discord API

Tags: java, discord

This is an oddly specific question but I'm trying to get the EventWaiter from JDA Utilities to work. (https://github.com/jagrosh/ExampleBot/tree/master/src/main/java/com/jagrosh/examplebot)

I have a method set up and the time out section works, but the waiter doesn't seem to pick up any new messages sent to discord like it is supposed to and I'm not sure why. Here is what I have:

```
public static void askQuestions(int numLeft, MessageReceivedEvent event, String level) {
            if(numLeft==0) {
                Writer.listWords(event);
                Writer.clearWords();
                return;
            }
            //Get random line from text file and store in text.
            text = Reader.fileReader(level);
            //Get the question 
            word = getQuestion(text);
            //Get the answer
            ans = getAnswer(text, event);
            //Write word to txt file to print out later at end of game. 
            Writer.playedWordsWrite(word, ans);
            //Create image of word and send to discord
            imageCreator(word, event);

            //Set up waiter to get players' answers. Mention user who gets it right and then call the method again.
            waiter.waitForEvent(MessageReceivedEvent.class, 
                //Make sure it's the right answer in the same channel
                e -> e.getChannel().equals(event.getChannel()) && e.getMessage().getRawContent().equals(ans),
                //Respond, inserting the name they listed into the response
                e -> {
                    e.getChannel().sendMessage(e.getAuthor().getAsMention()+ " got it right!").queue();
                    askQuestions(numLeft-1, e, level);
                },

                //If the user takes more than 10 seconds, time out
                7, TimeUnit.SECONDS, () -> {
                    event.getTextChannel().sendMessage("Correct answer: "+ans).queue();
                    askQuestions(numLeft-1, event, level);
                }
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is not to store JDA objects, such as channels, because it would be better to compare their IDs as longs. It's possible that that's the issue. Try `e.getChannel().getIdLong() == event.getChannel().getIdLong()` otherwise, I'd guess its one of your methods such as `imageCreator` or `playedWordsWrite`